# onActivityResult() never called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have a problem with `onActivityResult()` and `setResult()`.

I started android development 1 week ago so sorry.

Could you help me?

here is a snippet of my code :

ListActivity function Click

```
    val myadapter = ItemAdapter();
    list_recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    list_recycler_view.adapter = myadapter
    val me = this;
        myadapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : ItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(item: Item) {
                val intent = Intent(me, DetailActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("item", item)
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2)
            }
        })
```

List activity function onActivityResult

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.d("reponse","coucou5");
        Log.d("reponse",requestCode.toString());
        Log.d("reponse",resultCode.toString());
        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            val item = data?.getParcelableExtra<Item>("item") as Item
            Log.d("reponse-update",item.toString());
            if (item == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Could not update! Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            //ItemListViewModel.update(item);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Note not saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

DetailActivity function on click

```
     btnSave.setOnClickListener{
            //other props
            item.gid = gid;
            item.distance = distance
            Log.d("reponse",item.toString());
            Log.d("reponse","coucou4");
            val returnIntent = intent
            returnIntent.putExtra("item", item)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
            finish()
        }
```

it seems that the `onActivityResult()` is never called

Comment: What is the `myadapter`?

Comment: i added the instance, do you want the class ?

Comment: Can you change this line 'setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)' to 'setResult(2, returnIntent)'.

Comment: nothing change, my `"coucou4"` text is displaying but not `"coucou5"` in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Can you try giving a new intent as  val returnIntent = new Intent() before setResult.

Comment: yes i tried it but it does not solve my problem

Comment: Does 'ListActivity' extend any other activity other than Activity/AppcompatActivity? Could you also try to change this line : 'val intent = Intent(me, DetailActivity::class.java)' to 'val intent = Intent(this@ListActivity, DetailActivity::class.java)'

Comment: no there is the declaration `class ListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {` i try to replace me with this@ListActivity, no change

Comment: Have you noticed any error on logcat? Also can you check the 'Run' tab for any error

Comment: I dont see any error only  verbose text

Comment: Is there any launchmode specified for ListActivity in manifest? or is the attribute noHistory=true set for ListActivity in manifest?

Comment: no : <activity android:name="com.example.example.activities.ListActivity" />

Comment: Is the control coming back to ListActivity or is it not displaying the activity at all?

Comment: Try passing the context like this: `val intent = Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity::class.java)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that i was declare 2 listener on the adapter so the startActivityForResult doesnt fire

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are not creating another intent to send the info back, please do this and check if that works for you.

Do this in your detail activity instead of your code just paste this.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener{
        //other props
        item.gid = gid;
        item.distance = distance
        Log.d("reponse",item.toString());
        Log.d("reponse","coucou4");
        Intent returnIntent = Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("item", item)
        setResult(2, returnIntent)
        finish()
    }
```

you are passing RESULT_OK which isn't required and it's processed by the Android framework itself.

Comment: `val returnIntent = Intent()
 returnIntent.putExtra("item", item)
setResult(2, returnIntent)
finish()` no change, text `coucou5` not displaying

Comment: try removing the second part of if statement for now. jus go like, `if(requestCode == 2)` and check if that works for now. and let me know if it didn't work and il look more into it. even though your answer is right i want just to see what happens.

Comment: please check this link out. https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example . I want to help you get through this so please update me after looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
val returnIntent = intent
```

For

```
val returnIntent = new Intent()
```

Comment: yes i did  `val returnIntent = Intent()` but nothing change